# Exception handling - Exception within a catch clause?

Tags: c#, loops, csv, exception

I am downloading data from text files into db tables.  The data in the files is occasionally corrupt at a field level (files are comma delimited .csv files)

I am reading each line into an object that represents the data line with properties that are the correct datatype.

If the read into the object fails due to dodgy data, I want to read the line into a similar object as the first one, only this one has all data types set to string so the read into it should not fal.

The idea being that I can create a collection of valid record objects which I will load in to the appropriate db table, and a collection of exceptions which I will load into an exceptions table.  These can then be dealt with later.

**So - the question:**
I am going to loop through the lines of the text file and load these into the object and add the object to a collection.  There will be a try/catch loop around this and if the object load fails, then in the catch section I will load the exception object and add this to the collection of exceptions.

However, what happens if the exception object load fails (for whatever reason).  Do I put a try/catch around that and log exceptions - i.e a try/catch within a try/catch?

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I would say try to avoid putting code that can fail in the catch section. Maybe you can add the exception to a list, ie a process that wont fail, then handle it after you are done with the first parse.

Answer (score 5):

1. Code within a `catch` block is no way different to other code.

So you will have to protect every critical action with a `try catch` otherwise your program might crash.

2.
This might be a personal flavor, but I do not recommend to use `try` for control flow - do use `if` instead. So use if-statements to detect your dodgy data.

Comment: `try-catch` is indeed not to be used to control flow, that's an anti pattern of the highest degree.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can add the Try-Catch in other catch clause. It's OK.

Or as [Imapler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2885785/imapler) suggested, you can add the exception to a collection, and then process the collection in a loop. That's will let you process the lines with the exception later. But maybe it looks better than Try-Catch in a Catch clause.

```
var exceptionList = new List<ExceptionLines>();

try
{
    // read lines, parse...
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // handle the lines with the exception. Add the exception and the necessary arguments to the collection
    exceptionList.Add( new ExceptionLines(....));
}

// do stuff

// handle the exceptions.
foreach(var exception in exceptionList)
{
    try
    {
        // process the exception line.
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
          // log error and handle exception
    }
}
```

You can also wrap the exception with a wrapper. Maybe it will looks better.

```
// somewhere in your code...
WrapException( () =>
{
    // read and parse lines...
}, (ex) =>
{
    WrapException(ex, ParseToExceptionFunction, HandleExceptionParseFunction, false);

}, false);

void WrapException(Action func, Action<Exception> handleCatch, bool rethrow)
{
    try
    {
        func();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        handleCatch(ex);

        if (rethrow)
            throw;
    }
}

static void WrapException<T>(T arg, Action<T> func, Action<Exception> handleCatch, bool rethrow)
{
    try
    {
        func(arg);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        handleCatch(ex);

        if (rethrow)
                throw;
    }
}

void ParseToExceptionFunction(ArgType arg)
{
    // try to parse to excetion
}

void HandleExceptionParseFunction(Exception ex)
{
    // handle the exception for parsing the line with the exception
}
```

You can also implement the ParseToExceptionFunction and the HandleExceptionParseFunction as lambdas...

Answer (score 0):

So I used everybody's advice.

Used if than else's to catch dodgy data, created a list of good data and a list of exceptions (raised by the if and else's) and then processed the lists in try / catches to catch any other exceptions that may arile (ref integrity issues etc)

Thanks for the advice.